# Как получить данные из EditText'a

Tags: java, android

Есть диалог с собственным .xml, не могу получить данные из EditText, findViewById возвращает null.
**Код диалога:**

```
public void hostDialogue() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Добавить хост");
    alert.setMessage("Введите адрес и порт малинки");

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_host_dealogue, null);
    alert.setView(view);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            EditText ip = findViewById(R.id.ip_input);
            EditText port = findViewById(R.id.port_input);
            Log.e(TAG, ip.getText().toString());
            Log.e(TAG, port.getText().toString());
            // Do something with value!
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

**Код .xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip_input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="IP"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.079"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/port_input"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="PORT"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.189"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ip_input"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: view.findViewById(R + попросит сделать переменную final

Comment: @Style-7 Помогло, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [Style-7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/311415/style-7)

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_host_dealogue, null);
alert.setView(view);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            EditText ip = view.findViewById(R.id.ip_input);
            EditText port = view.findViewById(R.id.port_input);
            Log.e(TAG, ip.getText().toString());
            Log.e(TAG, port.getText().toString());
            // Do something with value!
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```